# Тостер работает некорректно

Tags: jquery, ajax, toast

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#upload").click(
        function () {
            sendUploadForm('uploadfile', 'uploadfile.php');
            return false;
        },
        function () {

            var valid = true;

            if (document.uploadfile['uploadedfile'].value === "" || document.uploadfile['folder'].value === "") {
                toastr.warning('Не выбран каталог или файл для загрузки', 'Внимание!', {"timeOut": 3000});
                valid = false;
            } else {                    
                var formUpload = new FormData(document.forms.uploadfile);
                formUpload.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    url: "uploadfile.php",
                    data: formUpload,
                    success: function () {
                        toastr.success('Файл успешно загружен', 'Отлично!', {"timeOut": 3000});
                        jQuery('#uploadfile')[0].reset();
                    }
                });
            }
            return valid;
        }
     );
   });
```

В целом работает исправно, за исключением сообщения об успешной загрузке файла, т.е. второй тостер не работает. Скорее всего расположен этот блок не в том месте. Подскажите, в чем ошибка...

Comment: поставьте после     `success: function () {`  `console.log(toastr);`

Comment: Поставил, однако,... прошу прощения за свою безграмотность, но где и что я должен увидеть? При этом в консоли Chroma нет никаких связанных ошибок...

Comment: В панеле для разработчиков. Если на Windows (F12), В вкладке консоле, если нет ничего, после загрузки файлов, тогда проблема не тостах, а в ответе

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит в ответе?! Подтверждение успешной загрузки - такой же тостер, что и первый. Так первый работает вполне успешно, а вот второй не отрабатывается. Ошибок в консоле нет, от слова совсем. Вот и не могу понять, что не так... ((

Comment: Если вы добавили консоль лог в метод success и после этого у Вас он в отображается в консоле браузера, тогда проблема у Вас с методом success, а не тостером

Comment: Вот только что вместо тостера поставил простой Алерт и успешно получил стандартное уведомлений. Голову уже сломал окончательно ((